# How do I save an IP camera Live feed to an avi file using AForge?

Tags: c#, video

First off, sorry if this is the wrong place for this post, but I don't usually post in forums. I have been stuck on a problem and cannot figure it out so I've finally decided to ask for help. Also, I am very new to C#.

Ok, so I have a live stream from an IP camera that I want to save to an avi file. Here is my code, it is very messy with lots of things commented out because I've been trying so many things. The code does open the stream so I can view it, and it creates an avi file of the name I choose. However, when you open that avi file, it is just black for however long you choose, in this case 40 seconds. I think my main problem is not knowing where to add in this piece of code:
    int width  = 320;
    int height = 240;

```
// create instance of video writer
VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter( );
// create new video file
writer.Open( "test.avi", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4 );
// create a bitmap to save into the video file
Bitmap image = new Bitmap( width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb );
// write 1000 video frames
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    image.SetPixel( i % width, i % height, Color.Red );
    writer.WriteVideoFrame( image );
}
writer.Close( );
```

I have tried many things and am just stuck! Can someone please help? Here is my code, and the stuff commented out is me just trying stuff and seeing what sticks, so to speak:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Controls;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace _11GVideoFeed
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MJPEGStream jpegSource1 = new MJPEGStream("IpCameraFeed");
        VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            jpegSource1.Login = "login";
            jpegSource1.Password = "password";
            Player.VideoSource = jpegSource1;
            //Player.VideoSource.Start();

            //VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
            //Create new AVI file and open it
            //writer.Open("test102.avi", 320, 240, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4);
            //Create frame image

            //Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(320, 240);

            //for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            //{
            //    //image1.SetPixel(i % 320, i % 240, Color.Red);
            //    //add the image as a new frame of video file
            //    writer.WriteVideoFrame(image1);

            //}
            //writer.Close();


        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Player.VideoSource.Stop();
            jpegSource1.Stop();
        }

        private void jpegSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap FrameData = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
            Player.BackgroundImage = FrameData;

        }

        private void jpegSource_VideoSourceError(object sender, AForge.Video.VideoSourceErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Description);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
            jpegSource1.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(jpegSource_NewFrame);
            jpegSource1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(jpegSource_VideoSourceError);


        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player.VideoSource.Start();
            writer.Open("test1000.avi", 320, 240, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4);
            Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(320, 240);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                //image1.SetPixel(i % 320, i % 240, Color.Red);
                //add the image as a new frame of video file
                writer.WriteVideoFrame(image1);

            }
            //writer.Close();
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player.VideoSource.Stop();
            writer.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Implementation questions should be posted on StackOverflow. This is off topic for Programmers.SE. One of the mods can migrate it to SO.